# Display at most X elements in HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html list, which contains visible and hidden elements. The visibility changes dynamically over time (some elements become hidden, some are shown).

```
<ul>
   <li>  </li>
   <li style="display:none">  </li>
   <li>  </li>
   <li style="display:none">  </li>
   <li>  </li>
   <li>  </li>
   <li>  </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is the list to display at most X elements, so `<li>`s beyond X should be hidden. What is the suggested way of achiving that? I've come up with two ideas:

- Set constant size of `<ul>` and add `overflow: hidden` (overhead `<li>`'s won't be visible). It's simple but will work only when `<li>`'s have constant size and you can predict number of elements that will fit into the list.
- Use javascript (I use jQuery) to count number of visible elements and hide the one's that should be hidden.

Can you suggest preferred approach or answer if there is a way to do that in pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`gt()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) selector, along with [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$('li:visible:gt(20)').hide()
```

Alternatively, use `slice()`:

```
$('li:visible').slice(20).hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function which controlls hiding of visible elements

```
function checkList()
{    
    $('ul li:visible:gt(X)').hide(); 
}
```

and you need to call the function on every change to UL and it's LIs. 
I would suggest some more identification to UL, perhaps via ID attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Using nth child selector you can achive it with pure css. But be aware that  IE does not support it.

In this example instead of applying **display:none**, I applied a **color:#ff0000** so you can appreciate the result.
Replace the 4 for the number of LI elements needed to be displayed.

```
<style> 
     ul li:nth-child(1n+4)
     {
       color:#ff0000;
     }
 </style>


<ul> 
  <li> a </li>
  <li> b  </li>
  <li> c </li>
  <li> d</li>
  <li> e </li>
  <li> f </li>
  <li> g </li>
 </ul>
```